# Nodejs and Electron - Where to save files on OS X El Capitan

Tags: node.js, osx-elcapitan, electron

I am working on an application that needs to save a configuration file. The application is going to be installed for all users so storing the config in *"/Users/someuser/Library/Application Support/MyApp/config.file"* is not an option.

Logic would dictate that I should store it in the global *"/Library/Application Support/"* directory, but I don't have permission to write to that directory. What is the standard convention for storing files on the Mac?

Comment: Usually all applications are installed for all users, yet they all provide mechanism for all users to have different configuration. Why is it not an option for you?

Comment: The nature of the configuration is such that all users use the same configuration. The app connects to an web app and the server address needs to be stored. All users will connect to the same server. But not all installs will connect to the same server - different clients connect to different servers, so the server address cannot be hardwired in the app, it needs to be set on install.

Comment: You could write to your app folder (e.g., use `app.getPath('exe')` or `__dirname`) though there are limitations if you're using `asar` to package your app.